# Unexpected results when retrieving data from Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

We are using Redis to store our Data(Fetched from multiple servers). This Data is stored against a key which is prepared on the basis of searched parameters and according to the prepared key we are serving the Data.
Now this works(returns expected Data) fine for 90% of the time, but sometimes it just returns NO RESULT for that particular key, despite of the fact that Data against that Key exists in the Redis( I verified it by running keys * command).
I do not observe any errors or Exceptions in my logs, so I am completely clueless about what is causing this anomalous behaviour.

Since this is occurring very erratic I am not able to resolve this. Any Idea what could be the issue which might cause Redis to behave in this manner?

PS : I update the data against the given key asynchronously so that the user is served latest data when he queries with same key next time.

Comment: Which client are you using, that only returns correct results 90% of the time even though terminal client returns it 100% of the time with `keys *` ?

Comment: And what are the total type of operations being performed on that key ? You can write some debug log for that

Comment: If you can reproduce the error on other environments then you can use the MONITOR command http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR to see exactly what you are sending to Redis. You can run it also on production, but it will have a performance impact

Answer (score 0):

Using the available data from your question, it might be one of the following:

1. If you are using a master-slave setup for your redis server (writes on master, all reads on slaves), problems in network/communications between the master and slaves can be a real problem regarding consistency. A slave that is unable to get the updates from the master will return erratic results (master Redis nodes replies a positive reply immediately even the changes hasn't been replicated to its slaves). If this is the case, I suggest trying the `WAIT` command. See the official Redis documentation for more info.
2. A more common mistake (even on my company's setup) is not checking if there are "rouge" clients connecting and mutating the data. Just using `KEYS` won't help that much if these clients modify the data faster than our eyes. Try isolating the setup on another set of machines and see if the problem persist. You may also replace the clients one by one with dummies so that your setup won't be that much complicated and easier to debug.
3. Probably logic error on your end. You might want to edit your question or comment here the exact commands you are doing to the said keys. That will really help with the debugging. You can do some synchronization via Redis or other methods to avoid race conditions or other similar problems.

Please describe your problem more in detail so that we can help you better. The actual commands, the client and server setup, the libraries used, and the Redis version will greatly help.